# Where do I put IF statement on my HTML page?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6

I am trying to get my website showing properly on ie6  and ie7 and they say that you must put use this statement:

```
 <!--[if IE 6]> <link href="ie6.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> <![endif]-->
```

Now where do I put this statement in my HTML page?

---

EDIT:

So I've added this just after the doctype:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org
  /TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <!--[if lt IE 7]><html class="ie6" lang="en"><![endif]-->
  <!--[if IE 7]><html class="ie7" lang="en"><![endif]-->
  <!--[if IE 8]><html class="ie8" lang="en"><![endif]-->
  <!--[if gt IE 8]><!--><html lang="en"><!--<![endif]-->
  <head>
```

In my style sheet ie6.css I've got this:

```
.ie6 #magazine_style_left {
position:relative;
float:left;
width:150px;
font-family:Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
font-size:14px;
color:#999999;
font-style:italic;
line-height:18px;

}

.ie6 #magazine_style_right {
position:relative;
float:right;
width:519px;
border-left: 1px solid #F2F2F2;
}
```

and I've added the css on the same page and it still isn't working. Its like its not picking up / using the ie6 css

Answer (score 5):

inside the head tag

```
<head>
<!--[if IE 6]> <link href="ie6.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> <![endif]-->
</head>
```

Answer (score 4):

It might help clarify things to mention this:

IE [conditional comments](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html), such as `<!--[if IE 6]><![endif]-->` can go pretty much* anywhere in the document. In the `<head>`, in the `<body>`, in an `<li>` element or `<form>`, etc. The content inside it (which can be anything*) will be rendered (or not) according to the rule used.

<sup>* There may be exceptions, but I'm not aware of any specific ones.</sup>

Knowing this, the question really boils down to "Where do I put a `<link>` tag", which is of course in the `<head>` as mentioned by the other answers.

There's another way to target IE, outlined here:

http://paulirish.com/2008/conditional-stylesheets-vs-css-hacks-answer-neither/

> For sometime now, the standards community has rallied around
>   conditional stylesheets as a solution to the validation problem.
>
> There are a few problems with it though:
>
> - Conditional stylesheets mean 1 or 2 additional HTTP requests to download
> - As they are in the the , the rendering of the page waits until they're totally loaded.
> - Also – Yahoo's internal coding best practices do not recommend conditional stylesheets
> - It can separate a single CSS rule into multiple files. I've spent a lot of time wondering "Where the eff is that rule coming from!?"
>     when it turned out to be tucked away in a conditional stylesheet.
>
> Here's my proposed solution:
>
> ```
> <!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="ie6"> <![endif]-->
> <!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="ie7"> <![endif]-->
> <!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="ie8"> <![endif]-->
> <!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html>         <!--<![endif]-->
> ```
>
> Using the same conditional comments, we're just conditionally adding
>   an extra class onto the html tag. This allows us to keep our
>   browser-specific css in the same file:
>
> ```
> div.foo { color: inherit;}
> .ie6 div.foo { color: #ff8000; }
> ```
>
> Plus it totally validates and works in all browsers.

I highly suggest this technique for attacking IE, definitely worth checking out.

Comment: Hi - very informative! Thank you!

Ok, so I need to take away or half the padding in this css rule to function properly in ie6:

#magazine_style_left {
position:relative;
float:left;
width:150px;
padding-right:20px;
font-family:Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
font-size:14px;
color:#999999;
font-style:italic;
line-height:18px;

}

So you are saying I must Add this in my header:
<!--[if lt IE 6]>      <html class="ie6"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 6]>         <html class="ie6"> <![endif]-->

and add .ie6 to magazine_style_left, so it would look like:
.ie6 #magazine_style_left {...} ?

Comment: That's correct, using this technique you can use `.ie6 #magazine_style_left` to select the element only in IE6, from within your normal stylesheet. The IE conditional comments would be used in this case only to add the `ieX` class to the `html` element, and opens the tag. It goes after your doctype, before your `<head>` tag (the place the `<html>` tag always goes).

Comment: By the way, I'm sorry about you having to deal with IE6, I'm crying just because I have to support IE8!

Comment: IE has made our lives a misery!! I'm sorry to hear that, but you sound clued up! - surely this is a piece of cake for you?

I tried what you mentioned above - but its not working - Please see my EDIT in my question above.

Comment: I'm Getting this issue:
http://dustinbrewer.com/css-fix-for-the-double-margin-float-bug-in-ie6/

Scroll down to the image where the site is broken. My Right float is dropping below and to the right of my left float. I've learn't that it is the padding that IE6 doubles causing the floats to be too wide for the parent element, therefore dropping my right float div. Why do we have to live with IE!!

Comment: You don't use both the conditional stylesheet *and* the html tag class trick, you would use one or the other. Are you 100% sure you have the right path to the IE6 CSS file? Most importantly, you've got the html tag all wrong in your edit - you have 2 html tags showing to IE... Example document should look like this: http://pastie.org/3014614

Comment: Thanks... Please see my EDIT above - I have changed it. Still doesn't work and this time I put the css styles on the same page and not in an external style sheet.

Comment: I'm viewing my website on this website http://netrenderer.com/index.php which allows you to see what your website looks like in different browser versions

Comment: It's a bit of a mess. If you want to use this method, use the example document I linked to as a template. If you're not sure what's safe to edit, don't edit it. Other than that, I don't know how else to help other than suggest practicing the basics before attempting to tame IE6. Best of luck.

Answer (score 3):

Into the `<head>` next to your other CSS includes. That means of course that you have an `ie6.css` file that fixes IE6 specific problems.

Comment: Hi, ok I thought thats where it should go (under other css link href files). Yes I do have an ie6.css file with css but it doesn't seem to be working (hence why I was wondering if I had placed the statement in the wrong place)

Answer (score 0):

You should put it inside the `head` tag, probably right after your other css includes, because where definitions clash, includes further down the `head` tag will override earlier definitions.